# When to use PreparedStatement batch vs single dynamic PreparedStatement?

Tags: performance, jdbc, java-8, prepared-statement

I'm getting conflicting reports, but I'm fairly certain the second way is better.

Using JDBC 4, if given a list of parameters of variable length, is it more efficient to:

a) Create a prepared statement with a single parameter, and match it to one of the parameters in the variable length list. Then add that query to a batch, and do this for the rest of the list, finally executing the statements as a batch.

b) Create a single prepared statement with multiple ? parameters, assign each parameter to a value in the list, and execute the single query.

In terms of transactions, b makes fewer calls to the DB. It also results in less RAM usage I would assume, since 4 different queries should in theory take up more space than a single query with multiple parameters. Correct?

Comment: I don’t see how your second approach is going to work when you say you have a variable length list, unless you create a new statement for each list (size), which negates the purpose of a *prepared* statement. Besides that, there is no general answer to that, as it highly depends on the particular database and JDBC driver implementation.

Comment: That is the idea, that I'd be creating a new statement each time around, since that list will change from time to time. Most of the time it will be the same every time the program is run, and so caching could be helpful, but on a few occasions, it will be different, and unfortunately I have no way of predicting when those occasions will occur.

It's SQL Server 12 and JDBC 4.

If I understand you correctly, there's no benefit in my situation to PreparedStatement over Statement?

Comment: If the list size doesn’t change so often, you might get a benefit from the repeatedly used `PreparedStatement`. Whether a prepared batch performs better or worse, depends on the particular database and JDBC driver implementation, but that even applies to the performance benefit of `PreparedStatement`s in general. I encountered implementations with `PreparedStatement`s having no performance advantage over ordinary `Statement`s at all, more than once. I think, it’s easier for you to implement both approaches and benchmark…

Comment: Okay, so assuming I had both implementations readily available and could run them both, how would i benchmark the performance? Are there particular logs on SQL Server I should be looking at for this? Sorry, not a lot of database experience, but I learned enough to open a db connection in JDBC, leave it open while I'm using it instead of constantly opening and closing the connection, use PreparedStatements when possible, particularly when a statement doesn't change or should be cached for reuse, and to batch what i can/minimize transactions whenever possible.